# In SQL Server 2008 R2 script data missing on Script Wizard

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

In my SQL Server 2008 R2

Script Option Screen of Script Wizard under section Table/View Options Look I find Script Data row and want to turn the option to True but I fail.

I don't find any **script data option.** Why script data option missing on  my SQL Server 2008 R2? Is there any command to generate the insert data option.

Why this problem arise? how to solve it? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 111):

It looks like they removed it from that location. You can still do it by:

- Right clicking on the DB
- Click on tasks
- Click on generate scripts
- Go through the wizard and select your tables
- On the options page click the Advanced button
- Change the "Types of data to script" option, from the default "Schema only" to "Schema and data".

Answer (score 8):

In SQL Server 2008 R2 you can go on the DB, right click on DB -> Tasks -> Generate scripts. This is the wizard for scripting the objects (with or without data). Follow the stepts described on the first page. At the third stept, "Set Scripting Options", after you choose your way to save /publish your data, you go on "Advanced" and there, for General Options, at line "Types of data to script" you can choose to script also your data ("Schema and data").

[image: i.stack.imgur.com/tFqfO.jpg]