# Copy Table Data from Different Server DB to Different Server DB

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have table structure in one Server DB and                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    i want to copy data to another Server DB table.                                                    How to achieve it ? 
**Note: (Failed Cases)**
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              **Attempt 1:** I tried Backup and restore, it failed due to versioning issue (10.50.2500 not matching with 10.00.4064).
**Attempt 2:** Export and Import, with validation error and etc...no copy from source to destination
**Attempt 3:** (failed due to different servers)

```
INSERT INTO [DB_NAME]..[dbo].[TABLE_NAME] 
     SELECT * FROM [DB_NAME]..[dbo].[TABLE_NAME]
```

(instead of above syntax i used like this also it have parsing error)

```
INSERT INTO [SERVER_NAME].[DB_NAME]..[dbo].[TABLE_NAME] 
SELECT * FROM [SERVER_NAME].[DB_NAME]..[dbo].[TABLE_NAME]
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do this -

**1. Generate CVS by this script and do export data (it's working for any table structure):**

```
DECLARE 
      @TableName SYSNAME
    , @ObjectID INT

DECLARE [tables] CURSOR READ_ONLY FAST_FORWARD LOCAL FOR 
    SELECT 
          '[' + s.name + '].[' + t.name + ']'
        , t.[object_id]
    FROM (
        SELECT DISTINCT
              t.[schema_id]
            , t.[object_id]
            , t.name
        FROM sys.objects t WITH (NOWAIT)
        JOIN sys.partitions p WITH (NOWAIT) ON p.[object_id] = t.[object_id]
        WHERE p.[rows] > 0
            AND t.[type] = 'U'
    ) t
    JOIN sys.schemas s WITH (NOWAIT) ON t.[schema_id] = s.[schema_id]
    WHERE t.name IN ('<your_table_name>')

OPEN [tables]

FETCH NEXT FROM [tables] INTO 
      @TableName
    , @ObjectID

DECLARE 
      @SQLInsert NVARCHAR(MAX)
    , @SQLColumns NVARCHAR(MAX)
    , @SQLTinyColumns NVARCHAR(MAX)

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 BEGIN

    SELECT 
          @SQLInsert = ''
        , @SQLColumns = ''
        , @SQLTinyColumns = ''

    ;WITH cols AS 
    (
        SELECT 
              c.name
            , datetype = t.name
            , c.column_id
        FROM sys.columns c WITH (NOWAIT)
        JOIN sys.types t WITH (NOWAIT) ON c.system_type_id = t.system_type_id AND c.user_type_id = t.user_type_id
        WHERE c.[object_id] = @ObjectID
            AND c.is_computed = 0
            AND t.name NOT IN ('xml', 'geography', 'geometry', 'hierarchyid')
    )
    SELECT 
          @SQLTinyColumns = STUFF((
            SELECT ', [' + c.name + ']'
            FROM cols c
            ORDER BY c.column_id
            FOR XML PATH, TYPE, ROOT).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 2, '')
        , @SQLColumns = STUFF((SELECT CHAR(13) +
            CASE 
                WHEN c.datetype = 'uniqueidentifier' 
                    THEN ' + '';'' + ISNULL('''' + CAST([' + c.name + '] AS VARCHAR(MAX)) + '''', ''NULL'')' 
                WHEN c.datetype IN ('nvarchar', 'varchar', 'nchar', 'char', 'varbinary', 'binary') 
                    THEN ' + '';'' + ISNULL('''' + CAST(REPLACE([' + c.name + '], '''', '''''''') AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) + '''', ''NULL'')' 
                WHEN c.datetype = 'datetime'
                    THEN ' + '';'' + ISNULL('''' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, [' + c.name + '], 120) + '''', ''NULL'')' 
                ELSE 
                ' + '';'' + ISNULL(CAST([' + c.name + '] AS NVARCHAR(MAX)), ''NULL'')'
            END
            FROM cols c
            ORDER BY c.column_id
            FOR XML PATH, TYPE, ROOT).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 10, 'CHAR(13) + '''' +')

    DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX) = '    
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    DECLARE 
          @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX) = ''''
        , @x INT = 1
        , @count INT = (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM ' + @TableName + ')

    IF EXISTS(
        SELECT 1
        FROM tempdb.dbo.sysobjects
        WHERE ID = OBJECT_ID(''tempdb..#import'')
    )
        DROP TABLE #import;

    SELECT ' + @SQLTinyColumns + ', ''RowNumber'' = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ' + @SQLTinyColumns + ')
    INTO #import
    FROM ' + @TableName + ' 

    WHILE @x < @count BEGIN

        SELECT @SQL = STUFF((
        SELECT ' + @SQLColumns + ' + ''''' + '
        FROM #import 
        WHERE RowNumber BETWEEN @x AND @x + 9
        FOR XML PATH, TYPE, ROOT).value(''.'', ''NVARCHAR(MAX)''), 1, 1, '''')

        PRINT(@SQL)

        SELECT @x = @x + 10

    END'

    EXEC sys.sp_executesql @SQL

    FETCH NEXT FROM [tables] INTO 
          @TableName
        , @ObjectID

END

CLOSE [tables]
DEALLOCATE [tables]
```

***Output:***

```
1;EM;0;NULL;Ken;J;Sánchez;NULL;0;92C4279F-1207-48A3-8448-4636514EB7E2;2003-02-08 00:00:00
2;EM;0;NULL;Terri;Lee;Duffy;NULL;1;D8763459-8AA8-47CC-AFF7-C9079AF79033;2002-02-24 00:00:00
3;EM;0;NULL;Roberto;NULL;Tamburello;NULL;0;E1A2555E-0828-434B-A33B-6F38136A37DE;2001-12-05 00:00:00
4;EM;0;NULL;Rob;NULL;Walters;NULL;0;F2D7CE06-38B3-4357-805B-F4B6B71C01FF;2001-12-29 00:00:00
```

**2. Generate INSERT statements by this script and insert data (it's working for any table structure):**

```
DECLARE 
      @TableName SYSNAME
    , @ObjectID INT
    , @IsImportIdentity BIT = 1

DECLARE [tables] CURSOR READ_ONLY FAST_FORWARD LOCAL FOR 
    SELECT 
          '[' + s.name + '].[' + t.name + ']'
        , t.[object_id]
    FROM (
        SELECT DISTINCT
              t.[schema_id]
            , t.[object_id]
            , t.name
        FROM sys.objects t WITH (NOWAIT)
        JOIN sys.partitions p WITH (NOWAIT) ON p.[object_id] = t.[object_id]
        WHERE p.[rows] > 0
            AND t.[type] = 'U'
    ) t
    JOIN sys.schemas s WITH (NOWAIT) ON t.[schema_id] = s.[schema_id]
    WHERE t.name IN ('<your_table_name>')

OPEN [tables]

FETCH NEXT FROM [tables] INTO 
      @TableName
    , @ObjectID

DECLARE 
      @SQLInsert NVARCHAR(MAX)
    , @SQLColumns NVARCHAR(MAX)
    , @SQLTinyColumns NVARCHAR(MAX)

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 BEGIN

    SELECT 
          @SQLInsert = ''
        , @SQLColumns = ''
        , @SQLTinyColumns = ''

    ;WITH cols AS 
    (
        SELECT 
              c.name
            , datetype = t.name
            , c.column_id
        FROM sys.columns c WITH (NOWAIT)
        JOIN sys.types t WITH (NOWAIT) ON c.system_type_id = t.system_type_id AND c.user_type_id = t.user_type_id
        WHERE c.[object_id] = @ObjectID
            AND (c.is_identity = 0 OR @IsImportIdentity = 1)
            AND c.is_computed = 0
            AND t.name NOT IN ('xml', 'geography', 'geometry', 'hierarchyid')
    )
    SELECT 
          @SQLInsert = 'INSERT INTO ' + @TableName + ' (' + STUFF((
            SELECT ', [' + c.name + ']'
            FROM cols c
            ORDER BY c.column_id
            FOR XML PATH, TYPE, ROOT).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 2, '') + ')'
        , @SQLTinyColumns = STUFF((
            SELECT ', ' + c.name
            FROM cols c
            ORDER BY c.column_id
            FOR XML PATH, TYPE, ROOT).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 2, '')
        , @SQLColumns = STUFF((SELECT CHAR(13) +
            CASE 
                WHEN c.datetype = 'uniqueidentifier' 
                    THEN ' + '', '' + ISNULL('''''''' + CAST([' + c.name + '] AS VARCHAR(MAX)) + '''''''', ''NULL'')' 
                WHEN c.datetype IN ('nvarchar', 'varchar', 'nchar', 'char', 'varbinary', 'binary') 
                    THEN ' + '', '' + ISNULL('''''''' + CAST(REPLACE([' + c.name + '], '''''''', '''''''''''' ) AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) + '''''''', ''NULL'')' 
                WHEN c.datetype = 'datetime'
                    THEN ' + '', '' + ISNULL('''''''' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, [' + c.name + '], 120) + '''''''', ''NULL'')' 
                ELSE 
                ' + '', '' + ISNULL(CAST([' + c.name + '] AS NVARCHAR(MAX)), ''NULL'')'
            END
            FROM cols c
            ORDER BY c.column_id
            FOR XML PATH, TYPE, ROOT).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 10, 'CHAR(13) + '', ('' +')

    DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX) = '    
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    DECLARE 
          @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX) = ''''
        , @x INT = 1
        , @count INT = (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM ' + @TableName + ')

    IF EXISTS(
        SELECT 1
        FROM tempdb.dbo.sysobjects
        WHERE ID = OBJECT_ID(''tempdb..#import'')
    )
        DROP TABLE #import;

    SELECT ' + @SQLTinyColumns + ', ''RowNumber'' = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ' + @SQLTinyColumns + ')
    INTO #import
    FROM ' + @TableName + ' 

    WHILE @x < @count BEGIN

        SELECT @SQL = ''VALUES '' + STUFF((
        SELECT ' + @SQLColumns + ' + '')''' + '
        FROM #import 
        WHERE RowNumber BETWEEN @x AND @x + 9
        FOR XML PATH, TYPE, ROOT).value(''.'', ''NVARCHAR(MAX)''), 1, 2, CHAR(13) + '' '') + '';''

        PRINT(''' + @SQLInsert + ''')
        PRINT(@SQL)

        SELECT @x = @x + 10

    END'

    EXEC sys.sp_executesql @SQL

    FETCH NEXT FROM [tables] INTO 
          @TableName
        , @ObjectID

END

CLOSE [tables]
DEALLOCATE [tables]
```

***Output:***

```
INSERT INTO [Person].[Person] ([BusinessEntityID], [PersonType], [NameStyle], [Title], [FirstName], [MiddleName], [LastName], [Suffix], [EmailPromotion], [rowguid], [ModifiedDate])
VALUES 
  (1, 'EM', 0, NULL, 'Ken', 'J', 'Sánchez', NULL, 0, '92C4279F-1207-48A3-8448-4636514EB7E2', '2003-02-08 00:00:00')
, (2, 'EM', 0, NULL, 'Terri', 'Lee', 'Duffy', NULL, 1, 'D8763459-8AA8-47CC-AFF7-C9079AF79033', '2002-02-24 00:00:00')
, (3, 'EM', 0, NULL, 'Roberto', NULL, 'Tamburello', NULL, 0, 'E1A2555E-0828-434B-A33B-6F38136A37DE', '2001-12-05 00:00:00')
, (4, 'EM', 0, NULL, 'Rob', NULL, 'Walters', NULL, 0, 'F2D7CE06-38B3-4357-805B-F4B6B71C01FF', '2001-12-29 00:00:00')
, (5, 'EM', 0, 'Ms.', 'Gail', 'A', 'Erickson', NULL, 0, 'F3A3F6B4-AE3B-430C-A754-9F2231BA6FEF', '2002-01-30 00:00:00')
, (6, 'EM', 0, 'Mr.', 'Jossef', 'H', 'Goldberg', NULL, 0, '0DEA28FD-EFFE-482A-AFD3-B7E8F199D56F', '2002-02-17 00:00:00')
, (7, 'EM', 0, NULL, 'Dylan', 'A', 'Miller', NULL, 2, 'C45E8AB8-01BE-4B76-B215-820C8368181A', '2003-03-05 00:00:00')
, (8, 'EM', 0, NULL, 'Diane', 'L', 'Margheim', NULL, 0, 'A948E590-4A56-45A9-BC9A-160A1CC9D990', '2003-01-23 00:00:00')
, (9, 'EM', 0, NULL, 'Gigi', 'N', 'Matthew', NULL, 0, '5FC28C0E-6D36-4252-9846-05CAA0B1F6C5', '2003-02-10 00:00:00')
, (10, 'EM', 0, NULL, 'Michael', NULL, 'Raheem', NULL, 2, 'CA2C740E-75B2-420C-9D4B-E3CBC6609604', '2003-05-28 00:00:00');
```

**3. Use any data comparator like:** [dbForge Data Compare for SQL Server](http://www.devart.com/dbforge/sql/datacompare/)

**4. Use the linked servers:** [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff772782.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can set a source DB as a [Linked Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa213778(v=sql.80).aspx) on a destination DB

Then just execute on the destination DB:

```
SELECT * INTO [TABLE_NAME] FROM [SOURCEDB]..[dbo].[TABLE_NAME]
```

This command creates table structure and inserts all rows from source to destination.

If you need to transfer Indexes, constraints, .... you can use a **"Generate Script"** Enterprise Manager interface command in MS SQL server.

Also on SQL 2008  you can use generate script interface command with data included. So all you need is to generate script on source DB for your table(s) and run this script on the destination DB.
Here are some links:

[SQL SERVER – 2008 – Copy Database With Data – Generate T-SQL For Inserting Data From One Table to Another Table](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/07/29/sql-server-2008-copy-database-with-data-generate-t-sql-for-inserting-data-from-one-table-to-another-table/)

[SO: In SQL Server 2008 R2 script data missing on Script Wizard](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4368064/1554034)